# Problem with const_iterator being called outside class

Tags: c++, templates, generics, vector, iterator

I have a classe called `Nuage` with the implementation:

**nuage.hpp**

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>

class Nuage {
    private:
        vector<T> v;
        static vector<T>::const_iterator it;

    
    public:
        Nuage();
        void ajouter(T);
        int size();
        T& begin();
        ~Nuage();
};
```

**nuage**.cpp

```
template <typename T>
Nuage<T>::Nuage(){}

template <typename T>
void Nuage<T>::ajouter(T p) {
    v.push_back(p);
}

template <typename T>
int Nuage<T>::size() {
    return v.size();
}

template <typename T>
T& Nuage<T>::begin(){
    return v.begin();
}

template <typename T>
Nuage<T>::~Nuage(){}
```

When i try to test the functioning of the class from a separate file, there are two errors with the following line of the code:
The following line is from a unit test that I can't change, so my code should adapt to it.
Nuage::const_iterator it = n.begin();

The unit test code is:

```
TEST_CASE ( "TP2_Nuage::Iterateurs" ) {
 Polaire p1(12,34);
 Polaire p2(56,78);
 Polaire p3(90,12);
 Polaire p4(34,56);

 Nuage<Polaire> n;

 n.ajouter(p1);
 n.ajouter(p2);
 n.ajouter(p3);
 n.ajouter(p4);

 Polaire t[4];
 unsigned i = 0;
 Nuage<Polaire>::const_iterator it = n.begin();

 while (it!=n.end()) t[i++]=*(it++);

 REQUIRE ( t[0].getAngle() == Approx(p1.getAngle()) );
 REQUIRE ( t[0].getDistance() == Approx(p1.getDistance()) );
 REQUIRE ( t[1].getAngle() == Approx(p2.getAngle()) );
 REQUIRE ( t[1].getDistance() == Approx(p2.getDistance()) );
 REQUIRE ( t[2].getAngle() == Approx(p3.getAngle()) );
 REQUIRE ( t[2].getDistance() == Approx(p3.getDistance()) );
 REQUIRE ( t[3].getAngle() == Approx(p4.getAngle()) );
 REQUIRE ( t[3].getDistance() == Approx(p4.getDistance()) );
}
```

The errors are:

```
error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::vector<T>::const_iterator’ because ‘std::vector<T>’ is a dependent scope

error: ‘const_iterator’ is not a member of ‘Nuage<Polaire>’
  Nuage<Polaire>::const_iterator it = n.begin()
```

Comment: Looks like you want `Nuage<Polaire>::it = n.begin();`. Please show the remaining code as well.

Comment: Could you describe the intended purposes and use case of the line `static vector<T>::const_iterator it;`? It's not clear to me what use a static member variable of that type would be and suspect you may have intended to perform a typedef instead.

Comment: @cigien  Nuage<Polaire>::const_iterator it = n.begin(); this is a part of a unit test that I can't change, it means that my code should adapt to this

Comment: I'm not saying you should change it, but we do need to see that code.

Comment: @cigien okay , I will put it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to expose the iterators of the underlying `vector` with things like `Nuage<T>::begin()`. If that's the case, I would suggest `public` `using` declarations, as well as making sure `begin` has the appropriate return type:

```
template <typename T>    
class Nuage {
    private:
        std::vector<T> v;
    
    public:
        using iterator = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
        using const_iterator = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;

        Nuage();
        void ajouter(T);
        int size();

        iterator begin();
        const_iterator begin() const;

        iterator end();
        const_iterator end() const;

        ~Nuage();
};
```

Here, my `using` declarations mean that `Nuage<T>::iterator` is the same type as `std::vector<T>::iterator`, and the `begin` functions return one.

I've also made a couple other changes to your code. I dropped the `using namespace std;` from the header file, since that's [pretty frowned-on behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). I also added a `const` version of `begin()` to make it more closely match the `std::vector` interface. And finally I've added declarations of `Nuage::end` functions, which will surely be needed for that unit test.